# Pass variables from Directive to Component

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table with a sort directive that sorts the table based on what header is clicked. I'd like to use `*ngIf` to show a symbol when the sort is in effect, however I need to pass the variables `this.key` and `this.togglesort` to the component when they are changed.

How can I do this?

My directive is:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSort]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  str1;
  str2

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }
      this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
    })
  }

  sortArray(): Array<any> {
    console.log( this.key, this.toggleSort) //CORRECTLY LOGS ITEMS
    .....
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I've created a [Stackblitz for this issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfbxg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Angular's EventEmitter and Output decorator.

The following code was added to the directive:

```
import { ...,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

...

export class SortDirective implements OnInit {
  ...

  @Output() onSortEvent = new EventEmitter();

  ...

  sortArray(): Array<any> {
  ...
  this.onSortEvent.emit({key: this.key, toggle: this.togglesort})
  // REVIEW: EventEmitter can only take one argument; passing object is workaround
  ...
  }
}
```

The HTML for each heading goes from:

```
<th appSort [sortKey]="'Id'" [data]="scorecardItems">Item ID</th>
<th appSort [sortKey]="'AccountNum'" [data]="scorecardItems">Account</th>
...
```

to:

```
<th appSort [sortKey]="'Id'" [data]="scorecardItems" (onSortEvent)="sortEventOnParent($event)">Item ID</th>
<th appSort [sortKey]="'AccountNum'" [data]="scorecardItems" (onSortEvent)="sortEventOnParent($event)">Account</th>
...
```

I can now log the variables from the component with:

```
sortEventOnParent(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

and can now use `*ngIf` with them after being converted to global variables.

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvpn7p).